# Prepared statement returns 0 instead of 1, why?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

What's the problem in this case? Why do I get 0 instead of 1? If i run the query from phpMyAdmin it works just fine.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?")){
        $input['hold'] = md5($input['pass'] . $config['salt']);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $input['user'], $input['hold']);
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0){
            // Set session variables
            $_SESSION['username'] = $input['user'];

            header("Location: members.php"); // Redirect if we have results }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your final queries are identical?

Comment: Do you know what `$stmt->store_result()` does and why are you calling it before `$stmt->execute()`?

Comment: why first line is conditional? explain please

Comment: Sidenote: Your password hashing scheme is extremely weak, MD5 with constant salt. Please have a look at the function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: @h2ooooooo - yes I am

Comment: @N.B. - execute is executing the query and store_result is bind the result (if I'm not wrong), I tried the other way around but does not work either

Comment: @nbin - I dont understand what do you mean

Comment: @martinstoeckli - I know md5 is weak and can be broken very easily, right now I want to get it up and working and only after then I will work on improving bits

Comment: You need to check whether $stmt->execute() returns true. If not, you need to check `$stmt->error_list` and see what's wrong.

Comment: @user3128078 - Ok, i wrote it partly because it also has an impact on the query. With a salted hash, you can search only for the username (not for the password), afterwards you have to verify the found password with a special function in PHP.

Comment: @user3128078 - Keep in mind that after the `header()` function the script continues to run. You should place an `exit();` afterwards, to be sure that trailing code is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but a few comments which are bit large for a comment.

The code you've shown us will set the session if the result is null, or fails as well as when the number of rows is zero. There is no error checking to see if the code is executing as expected.

You should be checking for errors. Also try running it with a hard-coded SQL statement which you have tested and verified using the mysql command line client of PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: I tried hardcoding it and I get: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement - any suggestions?